# making a side panel in default view to show the months calendar. react-big-calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am making a react calendar. When I am in my default view, which is today's day view, I want the months calendar (in typical calendar form) to show on the right hand side. Like an extra side panel.

I have been looking for a few hours and I haven't been able to find anyone/examples of something similar.

I am going to post a picture of my desired outcome. If anyone has come across something like thing, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a basic calendar control (Big Calendar would be overkill), in your right hand panel, and need some logic to sync displays in some way (probably by controlling your date prop at a higher level, and sharing between the two)